# Next / Previous Post Links from Same Category

Tags: wordpress

I am dealing with a very strange code for next/previous links in WP, I cannot seem to make it work ONLY in the same category.

I tried previous answers here, to no use.

```css
<?php
  the_post_navigation( array(
'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true"><span class="pagination__text">' . esc_html__( 'Next', 'nubia' ) . '</span><span class="pagination__icon" data-icon="ei-chevron-right" data-size="s"></span></span> ' .
'<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Next post:', 'nubia' ) . '</span>' .
'<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true"><span class="pagination__icon" data-icon="ei-chevron-left" data-size="s"></span><span class="pagination__text">' . esc_html__( 'Previous', 'nubia' ) . '</span></span>' .
'<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Previous post:', 'nubia' ) . '</span>' .
'<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
  ) );
?>
```

I only want help to actually change the appropriate line to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

THAT is the answer :)
just add this at both ends: 
  'in_same_term'               => true,

```html
<?php
  the_post_navigation( array(
    'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true"><span class="pagination__text">' . esc_html__( 'Next', 'nubia' ) . '</span><span class="pagination__icon" data-icon="ei-chevron-right" data-size="s"></span></span> ' .
    '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Next post:', 'nubia' ) . '</span>' .
    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',            'in_same_term'               => true,
    'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true"><span class="pagination__icon" data-icon="ei-chevron-left" data-size="s"></span><span class="pagination__text">' . esc_html__( 'Previous', 'nubia' ) . '</span></span>' .
    '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Previous post:', 'nubia' ) . '</span>' .
    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',            'in_same_term'               => true,
  ) );
?>
```